# How to add Fullscreen Video Background to Angular

Tags: html, angular

I am currently working on a angular project. In that project I want to add a video as its background for all components. How can I do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following code to `app.component.html`

```html
<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
  <source src="path_to_video" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

and

add following code to `app.component.css`

```css
 /* Style the video: 100% width and height to cover the entire window */
#myVideo {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

/* Add some content at the bottom of the video/page */
.content {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* Style the button used to pause/play the video */
#myBtn {
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#myBtn:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
```

for more details follow [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fullscreen_video.asp).

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to the answer above. If you are trying to make a video background on the page of the site, use onloadedmetadata="this.muted=true" instead of "muted". In this case, the video will play correctly after the page loads. Tested angular 17.